# How to use a pipe to edit a file with vi

Tags: macos, command-line, vim, shell, vi

Lets say I have a file called file.txt. In it is a name of a file that I want to edit with vi. I want to do something like this so that I can edit the file:

```
cat file.txt | vi
```

However, that doesn't work. How can it be done?

To clarify things:

Here are the contents of file.txt:

```
textfile
```

So I want to somehow send the contents of file.txt to vi so that the same thing will happen as when typing `vi textfile`.

The contents of file.txt can change. I want vi to edit whatever file is listed in file.txt.

Comment: I dont think that vi = vim. I dont know that that makes a difference for this question, but your tag is misleading.

Comment: I think there may be more to your question you're trying to ask. Opening an arbitrarily named file is the base usage of vi. i.e. : `vi file.txt`. Is there something more advanced you're trying to do?

Comment: vi starts vim on OSX and on other modern Linux systems.

Comment: I am actually trying to edit a file whose name is stored in the OSX clipboard. Typing pbpaste will display the filename. I'm trying to edit this file without actually having to type it, but by using whatever is stored in the clipboard. Linux doesn't have pbpaste, but it is essentially the same as getting the output from cat filename.

Comment: install `xclip` and then use `xclip -o` to access the clipboard on the shell in x11. just in case you need to replace `pbpaste`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you might try this:

```
% vi `cat file.txt`
```

or, to avoid the useles use of cat:

```
% vi `< file.txt`
```

you are telling vi(m) just a bunch of arbitrary things. if you want vi(m) to do something like 'hey, open that file' you have to feed it the same commands you would use in vi(m), eg. something like `:e foo.txt`. but thats just more complicated than doing what i proposed.

Comment: Those didn't work.

Comment: those are backticks, you typed them in correctly? they open a subshell, execute the 'cat' ... if that does not work, try  `vi $(cat file.txt)`

Comment: Oh ok, it works now. thx.

Answer (score 23):

At least for vim (not sure about vi), you can do

```
cat file.txt | vim -
```

The '-' tells vim to read from stdin.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the correct answer. This opens vim with the contents 'textfile'. The questioner wants vim to open 'textfile' itself. I'd downvote but sadly I don't have enough reputation here.

Comment: scubbo is right! My answer is more useful for just piping something from stdin.